# Finding the primality of an integer using C++

Tags: c++

Write a C++ algorithm to test for a prime number. My C++ codes are as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int x,n;
bool isprime(int);

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter prime no"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    for (n=2;n<=floor(sqrt(x));n++)
    {
        if (x==1)
            cout<<"not prime"<<endl;
        else if (x%n==0)
            cout<<"is not prime"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"prime"<<endl;
    }
}
```

But when i run the programn my output does not seem right for example i keep getting "is prime" when the answer is clearly is not prime.The

```
else if (x%n==0)
cout<<"is not prime"<<endl;
```

portion of the statement couldnt seem to be excuted properly.Could anyone explain to me what is wrong with my code. Thanks

Comment: If you haven't used a debugger before, now is the right time to learn how. With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while monitoring the variables and their values, and see how the variables change. If you do this you should hopefully find your problem pretty quickly.

Comment: You are making your decision during the first iteration of the `for` loop. To find out whether an integer is prime, you need to run the entire loop. You really need to fix your formatting to get better visual code flow.

Comment: Take `x=9` .`x` is not divisible by `n=2`.So you'll output as prime.Even though till now you haven't checked for `n=3` .Think what is wrong here.Hint: May be you want to check for all divisors then decide whether it is prime or not.

Comment: And a couple of other unrelated notes: First of all, don't use global variables. There's seldom a need for global variables, and in this case no need at all. Secondly, do input validation *before* the loop. For example, you don't need to check if `x` is `1` each iteration in the loop, only once before the loop, and there you should also check for zero or negative values of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop outputs "prime" for each non-divisor of x. You should terminate the loop after the first "not prime" hit and only output "prime" if the loop was not terminated.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Udo Klein, you should break out of the loop when it is has been detected that the number is not a prime. Also there is no need to check if `x` is equal to one inside the loop.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cout << "Enter prime no" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;

    if (x == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "not prime" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for (int n = 2; n <= floor(sqrt(x)); n++)
    {
        if (x % n == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "is not prime" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "prime" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```